# How to share a folder (directory) with an Android device?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, android, shared-folders

Step by step, how does one share a folder (directory) that is on a Windows 7 system with an Android device?

I want a true networking share (over Wifi), not an FTP connection.

I would prefer not to install any software on the Windows 7 system, and to use ES File Explorer on the Android device, but am open to all solutions.

BTW, I think I am doing everything correctly, but I must be missing a step.  When I get to the "Connecting to" dialog box in ES File Explorer, no matter what I enter, it does not work.  I've even tried guest/guest to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Make a Windows Home Network and then use 3rd party app on the Android to access the Network via your router. Make sure to Enable file sharing on your windows 7 Network. 
Try these links

http://www.howtogeek.com/191378/how-to-access-shared-windows-folders-on-android-ipad-and-iphone/

http://www.guidingtech.com/10885/access-shared-windows-folders-android-wifi/

I have done what you describe before, but my phone is so slow and I deleted that network. But I know I used one of these ways to do it.